# not reading values from config file after publishing Word Add-in using c#

Tags: c#, deployment, word-addins

I have created a word add-in type project using visual studio 2013. I'm using file location from config file. But after publishing the project using clickonce, it generates files with .deploy extension.
It works perfect, but when I'm trying to change the config file values. It still reads the old value.
Is there anything for not appending ".deploy" extension after publishing the add-in project? please help.

[Publish options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V0al.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Visual Studio not to add the .deploy extension to your published files.

In the solution explorer right click on your project and select "Properties".
(Project file (.csproj) not Solution(.sln)))

It will open the Project configuration module.

Select "Publish" (from the menu on the left hand side) and once on the Publish settings, click "Options...".

It will open a new dialog where you can see the "Deployment" menu on the left hand side.

Select that and then see for the checkbox "Use .deploy file extension". Un-check that and re-build your project and then publish it.

Comment: There is no "Deployment" menu inside publish option for Word Add-In Project type. Added the screenshot of publish option in question above

Comment: I see, what type of project did you use? Word Add iN?